# how to fix this"OSError: cannot identify image file " Opencv imwrite doesn't actually save image

Tags: python, image, opencv, face-recognition

I'm learning Opencv right now from this git

https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/blob/master/examples/facerec_from_webcam_faster.py

and add some code tocapture image, it does capture and save image to my specified path
but it doesn't show image it saved (sorry,i'm not sure what to call it) it say doesn't support this format file

![1]: https://ibb.co/zXp7PmY

i tried change format file to jpg,bmp,png
moved these code in/out of for loop
add

```
top = 200
right = 200
bottom = 200
left = 200
```

if not in imshow for loop

```
poor_match_index = np.argmax(face_distances)            
           if matches[poor_match_index]:
               cv2.imwrite("tanapat/unknown_" + str(count) + ".jpg", frame[right:left,top:bottom]) 
               unknown = face_recognition.load_image_file("tanapat/unknown_"+ str(count) +".jpg")
               unknown_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown )[0]
               known_face_encodings.append(unknown_encoding)
               known_face_names.append("unknown_"+str(count))
               name = known_face_names[poor_match_index]
               count +=1
               break
```

i tried to make it repeat to capture new face and recognize it(try to not make it continue to capture the same person too many frame)

but got error on line

```
unknown = face_recognition.load_image_file("tanapat/unknown_"+ str(count) +".jpg")
```

OSError: cannot identify image file 'tanapat/unknown_0.jpg'

Comment: did you check if you can open this file in any image viewer ?

Comment: using `200` for `top,bottom,right,left` you have `frame[200:200,200:200]` and you get empty array - without any pixel - so it may have problem to read image which doesn't have pixels.

Comment: if you run `print(cv2.imwrite(...))` then it should display `True` if it saved image, and `False` if it had problem to save it.

Comment: i checked,there's a image file but doesn't show any image (0bytes) .
i tried increase to be more than 200 `top,bottom,right,left` but  `print(cv2.imwrite(...))` still  `false`

Comment: if file has 0 bytes then there is no image inside so programs can't display it. They can't even load data with information if this is jpg or other format - they don't use file extension to recognize format. You can't use the same value for top and bottom because  `height = bottom - top = 200 - 200 = 0` and the same value for `right` and `left` because `width = right - left = 200 - 200 = 0` .

Comment: Thanks,problem solved now. i did mess up that axis value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use

```
top = 200
right = 200
bottom = 200
left = 200
```

then `frame[200:200,200:200]` creates empty array.

```
 width = right - left = 200 - 200 = 0
 height = bottom - top = 200 - 200 = 0
```

When you save empty array then you get empty file - my Linux shows size 0 for this `.jpg` - and you can't open empty file.

You need at least

```
top = 200
bottom = top + 1  # 201

left = 200
right = left + 1  # 201
```

to create file with one pixel - `frame[200:201,200:201]`.

---

If you use `print()` to display result from `imwrite()`

```
print(cv2.imwrite(...))
```

then you get `False` if it had problem to save file.